# Trying to find a way to automate when id is the same

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am having a hard time trying to automate three text fields with the same input id on Selenium WebDriver using Java (Chrome). Below is the website information for the links.

For CC

```html
<input
    id="recurly-hosted-field-input"
    type="tel"
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    spellcheck="false"
    autocapitalize="none"
    autocorrect="off"
    class="recurly-hosted-field-input unknown"
    placeholder="Credit Card Number"
    title="Credit Card Number"
    aria-required="true"
    autocomplete="cc-number"
    style="visibility: visible; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Lato, sans-serif; font-feature-settings: normal; font-kerning: auto; font-size: 17px; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; text-rendering: auto; text-shadow: none; text-transform: none;"
>
```

For Month

```html
<input
    id="recurly-hosted-field-input"
    type="tel"
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    spellcheck="false"
    autocapitalize="none"
    autocorrect="off"
    class="recurly-hosted-field-input"
    placeholder="Month (mm)"
    title="Month (mm)"
    maxlength="2"
    aria-required="true"
    autocomplete="cc-exp-month"
    style="visibility: visible; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Lato, sans-serif; font-feature-settings: normal; font-kerning: auto; font-size: 17px; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; text-rendering: auto; text-shadow: none; text-transform: none;"
>
```

This is the format Im currently using.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("213 Ave");
    driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("New York");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have an ID but it's not unique on the page since both `INPUT`s have the same ID. What I would do is start looking at the different attributes of the `INPUT`s and hopefully find something unique. In this case, I would assume that the `title` is unique on the page and would start there.

```
input[title='Credit Card Number']
input[title='Month (mm)']
```

These are both CSS selectors and they specify an `INPUT` tag with the attribute listed for the two tags you listed.

Answer (score 0):

When there is one ID that is not unique on the code, which is supposed to be impossible as is bad programmed, you should:

1st Option: Use another field that is not shared by the elements

2nd Option: Use the findElements(By by) option in order to get a list where you can iterate on. On that list you can see if the other parameters of the object are the ones you're looking for and then execute your code on it.

Also, on your code you're searching By.name, but there is no name tag on your xml. Try using the ID, and then select with the brakets[] the element you want, as @RKelley did told you. Give positive value to that well explained and elaborated answer, as is the correct one. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Xpath selectors for locating the similar fields.
I am assuming they are in single div or any other tag then you can access like

```
/<path_to_div>/input[0] -->will locate first
similiarly /<path_to_div>/input[1] -->will locate second abd so on..
```

You can get reference from here : https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html